Fixed $ u \in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2) $. Prove that $ \|u\|_{L^{\infty}}^2 \leq C\|u\|_{H^1}^2\left(1+\ln \frac{\|u\|_{H^2}}{\|u\|_{H^1}}\right) $.

Assume $ u \in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2) $. Prove that there exists a constant $ C $ such that
$$
\|u\|_{L^{\infty}}^2 \leq C\|u\|_{H^1}^2\left(1+\ln \frac{\|u\|_{H^2}}{\|u\|_{H^1}}\right) .
$$
Hint: Fourier transform can be used.

I can use Fourier transform to deal with the RHS because $\|f\|_{H^s}^2=\sum\limits_{k \leq s}\left\|\left.2 \pi \xi\right|^k \widehat{f}\right\|_{L^2}^2 \approx\left\|\left(1+|\xi|^2\right)^{\frac{s}{2}} \widehat{f}\right\|_{L^2}^2$. But I don't know how to use Fourier transform on $\|u\|_{L^{\infty}}$. I only have $\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}\le C\|f\|_{H^{s}}$ for $\forall f\in H^s(\mathbb R^n)$ and $s>\frac n2$. But it doesn't work. How can I deal with the "$\ln$"?

Proof: We use the standard Sobolev norms defined via the Fourier transform $\hat{u}(\xi)$:
$$
\|u\|_{H^1}^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} (1+|\xi|^2)|\hat{u}(\xi)|^2 \, d\xi, \quad
\|u\|_{H^2}^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} (1+|\xi|^2)^2 |\hat{u}(\xi)|^2 \, d\xi.
$$
Since $u$ is smooth and compactly supported, all these integrals and transforms are well-defined.
For a parameter $R > 1$, decompose $u$ into low and high frequency parts:
$$
u = u_{\le R} + u_{>R},
$$
where
$$
\hat{u}_{\le R}(\xi) = \hat{u}(\xi)\mathbf{1}_{\{|\xi|\le R\}}, \quad
\hat{u}_{>R}(\xi) = \hat{u}(\xi)\mathbf{1}_{\{|\xi|>R\}}.
$$

For the high-frequency part $|\xi| > R$, we have:
$$
u_{>R}(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{|\xi|>R}\hat{u}(\xi)e^{i x\cdot\xi}d\xi.
$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$
|u_{>R}(x)| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\int_{|\xi|>R}\frac{d\xi}{(1+|\xi|^2)^2}\right)^{1/2}\|u\|_{H^2}.
$$
In polar coordinates $\xi=(\rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta)$, $\xi=\rho d\rho d\theta$:
$$
\int_{|\xi|>R}\frac{d\xi}{(1+|\xi|^2)^2} \le \int_{\rho>R}\frac{2\pi\rho}{\rho^4}d\rho = 2\pi\int_{R}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\rho^3}d\rho = \frac{\pi}{R^2}.
$$
Hence,
$$
|u_{>R}(x)| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{R^2}}\|u\|_{H^2} = \frac{C}{R}\|u\|_{H^2}.
$$
Taking the supremum over $x$,
$$
\|u_{>R}\|_{L^\infty} \le \frac{C}{R}\|u\|_{H^2}.
$$
For $|\xi|\le R$:
$$
u_{\le R}(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{|\xi|\le R}\hat{u}(\xi)e^{ix\cdot\xi}d\xi.
$$
Using Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$
|u_{\le R}(x)| \le \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\int_{|\xi|\le R}(1+|\xi|^2)|\hat{u}(\xi)|^2 d\xi\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{|\xi|\le R}\frac{d\xi}{1+|\xi|^2}\right)^{1/2}.
$$

Since $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}(1+|\xi|^2)|\hat{u}(\xi)|^2 d\xi = \|u\|_{H^1}^2$,
$$
|u_{\le R}(x)| \le \frac{\|u\|_{H^1}}{2\pi}\sqrt{\int_{|\xi|\le R}\frac{d\xi}{1+|\xi|^2}}.
$$
In polar coordinates:
$$
\int_{|\xi|\le R}\frac{d\xi}{1+|\xi|^2} = 2\pi\int_0^R\frac{\rho}{1+\rho^2}d\rho = \pi\ln(1+R^2).
$$
Thus, taking the supremum over $x$,
$$
\|u_{\le R}\|_{L^{\infty}} \le \frac{\|u\|_{H^1}}{2\pi}\sqrt{\pi\ln(1+R^2)} \le C\|u\|_{H^1}\sqrt{\ln(1+R^2)}.
$$
As a result,
$$ \|u\|_{L^{\infty}}\leq \|u_{\le R}\|_{L^{\infty}}+\|u_{\ge R}\|_{L^{\infty}}\leq C\|u\|_{H^{1}}\sqrt{1+\ln(1+R^2)}+\frac{C}{R}\|u\|_{H^2}. $$
Let $R=\frac{\|u\|_{H^2}}{\|u\|_{H^{1}}}\geq 1$. It follows that
$$ \begin{aligned}  \|u\|_{L^{\infty}}^{2}&\leq C\|u\|_{H_{1}}^{2}\left(1+\ln\left(1+\frac{\|u\|_{H^2}}{\|u\|_{H^{1}}}\right)\right)\\
&\leq C\|u\|_{H_{1}}^{2}\left(1+\ln\frac{\|u\|_{H^2}}{\|u\|_{H^{1}}}+\ln\left(1+\frac{\|u\|_{H^1}}{\|u\|_{H^{2}}}\right)\right)\\ 
&\leq C\|u\|_{H_{1}}^{2}\left(1+\ln{2}+\ln\frac{\|u\|_{H^2}}{\|u\|_{H^{1}}}\right)\\
&\leq C\|u\|_{H_{1}}^{2}\left(1+\ln\frac{\|u\|_{H^2}}{\|u\|_{H^{1}}}\right).
\end{aligned}
$$

$\def \R{\mathbb R}$
$\def \RR{\mathbb R^2}$
$\def\jap#1{\langle #1\rangle}$
The other answer is nice. I wrote a sketch of a similar proof that captures some core ideas. Set $\jap{\xi}:=(1+|\xi|^2)^{1/2}$.

The Sobolev embedding $H^s(\RR)\hookrightarrow L^\infty(\RR)$ is true for any $s>1$, and fails for $s=1$. This indicates that the constant $C_s$ in the inequality
$$
\|u\|_{L^\infty}\leq C_s \|u\|_{H^s}
$$
blows up as $s\to 1^+$. You can compute the sharp constant explicitly by
$$
|u(x)|\leq \int_{\RR} \jap{\xi}^{-s}\jap{\xi}^{s}|u(\xi)|\,d\xi\leq \left(\int_{\RR} \jap{\xi}^{-2s}\,d\xi\right)^{1/2}\|u\|_{H^s}=:C_s \|u\|_{H^s}
$$
and check using your favourite techniques that $C_s\sim (s-1)^{-1/2}$ (I believe the correct exponent is $-1/2$). By complex interpolation,
$$
\|u\|_{H^s}\leq \|u\|_{H^1}^{2-s}\|u\|_{H^2}^{s-1}.
$$
Combining the two estimates,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|u\|_{L^\infty}&\leq C_s \left(\frac{\|u\|_{H^2}}{\|u\|_{H^1}}\right)^{s-1}\|u\|_{H^1}\\
&=C(s-1)^{-1/2} \exp((s-1)\log\left(\frac{\|u\|_{H^2}}{\|u\|_{H^1}}\right))\|u\|_{H^1}\\
&=:A_s\|u\|_{H^1}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, you have a family of estimates with different constants $A_s$, so you can optimize in $s$. There are many ways of optimizing a family of inequalities, often with a little bit of practice you can just guess the optimal $s$. Otherwise, a direct approach here is to study the function
$$
\tau(K):=\inf_{t\in (0,1]}t^{-1/2}\exp(tK).
$$
You can verify that $\tau(K)\leq C (1+K)^{1/2}$, and this proves your inequality.
This approach works in general for logarithmic types of interpolation inequalities.
